# R unraveling a data set

Tags: r, dataset

I want to unravel an R dataset and get it in long format. For instance, if I type HairEyeColor, I get

```
, , Sex = Male

        Eye
Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
Black    32   11    10     3
Brown    53   50    25    15
Red      10   10     7     7
Blond     3   30     5     8

, , Sex = Female

        Eye
Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
Black    36    9     5     2
Brown    66   34    29    14
Red      16    7     7     7
Blond     4   64     5     8
```

How do I get a list of all 542 in long format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the package `reshape2`

```
require(reshape2)
melt(HairEyeColor)
```

Clarification in comments confirms that what you want is to take the rows and repeat them rather than have that information *compressed* in the `value` column (as occurs by default).

To do this, as Tyler in comments, do the following:

```
x <- melt(HairEyeColor)
x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), x$value), -4]
```

The first line makes `x`, which is printed below.

The second line tells `R` to repeat the first row (the combination of `Hair`, `Eye`, `Sex`) `value` times.  The meaning of `-4` after the comma (as in `[..., -4]`) is to **NOT** include the fourth column (in this case `value`) when repeating the row.

Here's the output of `x` from the defaults for `melt`.

```
> melt(HairEyeColor)
   Hair   Eye    Sex value
1  Black Brown   Male    32
2  Brown Brown   Male    53
3    Red Brown   Male    10
4  Blond Brown   Male     3
5  Black  Blue   Male    11
6  Brown  Blue   Male    50
7    Red  Blue   Male    10
8  Blond  Blue   Male    30
9  Black Hazel   Male    10
10 Brown Hazel   Male    25
11   Red Hazel   Male     7
12 Blond Hazel   Male     5
13 Black Green   Male     3
14 Brown Green   Male    15
15   Red Green   Male     7
16 Blond Green   Male     8
17 Black Brown Female    36
18 Brown Brown Female    66
19   Red Brown Female    16
20 Blond Brown Female     4
21 Black  Blue Female     9
22 Brown  Blue Female    34
23   Red  Blue Female     7
24 Blond  Blue Female    64
25 Black Hazel Female     5
26 Brown Hazel Female    29
27   Red Hazel Female     7
28 Blond Hazel Female     5
29 Black Green Female     2
30 Brown Green Female    14
31   Red Green Female     7
32 Blond Green Female     8
```

Comment: This is close but not quite there. For instance, I would have 32 rows of combination 1, not having the 4th row as a "value". Of course I could write a loop to fix this but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: Did you use `?melt` and the rest of the **reshape2** package?  You have to do a bit of leg work, especially if you don't provide the desired output in your question.

Comment: That being said I think you want: `x <- melt(HairEyeColor); x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), x$value), -4]`

Comment: @user1357015 if you clarify what it is you'd like, i'll update the answer to reflect.  Is Tyler Rinker right about what you'd like?

Comment: Hey, yep, Tyler Rinker is right. :-) Can someone explain what the -4 does? I can't seem to figure that part out...

Comment: It sounds like you are pretty new to R.  It is indexing with a negative to say; remove column # 4.  I think you'd benifit from having a look at the [CRAN Intro Manual (click here)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html).

Comment: @user1357015 i updated the answer to reflect your clarification and added some explanation about how `x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), x$value), -4]` works its magic.

Answer (score 5):

Simple base R solution

```
as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
```

Comment: I often forget that `as.data.frame` is cooler than it appears. +1

Comment: Neither did I initially. But I have played so much with `HairEyeColor` that I learnt a lot of useful functions to deal with tabular data.

Comment: Does this still work for you guys? `as.data.frame()`  just gets me to the equivalent of the `melt()` function.